# Issue with mouse events in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a custom youtube player using JS API. I am trying to fadeout the player controls when i mouseout from the player and facein when i mousein on the player.

Following is the jQuery code i have used.

```
$("#video-container, #ytPlayer").on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#video-controls').fadeIn(500);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $('#video-controls').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Demo URL: http://staging.xhtml-lab.com/tik-o-talk/

The mouse events are not working properly, any suggestions please?

Comment: More often that not, you should use `mouseleave` in place of `mouseout` to avoid complications stemming from event-bubbling. If you are using `mouseout` the handler is fired not only when the mouse leaves the main element, but also when the mouse leaves any child element to enter another child element, something you rarely want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#video-container, #ytPlayer").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
    var fadeOpacity = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 1 : 0 ;
    $('#video-controls').stop().fadeTo( 500, fadeOpacity  );
});
```

Mouseenter and mouseout are the brothers of `hover` method, and more reliable for the enter/leave elements event, than adding a bit of `.stop()` to clear the animation queues and the  fantastic `fadeTo()` method should be the cherry to our recipe.

Comment: @Musa that is incorrect. If it's about misunderstanding , than my mentioned `queue` means `buildups` if that makes the term a bit more clear.

Comment: @Musa, if you read carefully the DOCS you'll see that `When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately.` that means that the queue of the previous animation gets cleared, without creating animation buildups. Correct me if I'm wrong :)